# What is the security model of VSCode Remote Development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

What is the security model of VSCode Remote Development? If the remote server is fully controlled by an attacker, is it possible for him/her to run arbitrary code on my local machine? Is there any PoC for this?

If the answer is yes, does [Restricted Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust) solve this problem? In my understanding, Restricted Mode only stops attacks from the project folder, while the attacker could also manipulate the vscode server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520294/how-secure-is-vscode-remote-ssh-for-the-local-machine. Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6608.